# Creating a list of dictionaries with default values

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a set of strings like:

```
('abc', 'def', 'xyz')
```

I want to use these strings as values of a key 'type' and to associate 2 extra key-value pairs to each, giving a default value to each extra key, like this:

```
resulting_list_of_dicts = [{'type' : 'abc' ,'extra_key1' : 0, 'extra_key2'  : 'no'}, 
                          {'type' : 'def' ,'extra_key1' : 0, 'extra_key2'  : 'no'}, 
                          {'type' : 'xyz' ,'extra_key1' : 0, 'extra_key2'  : 'no'}]
```

How can I do this (smartly) in Python 2.7?

Comment: `dict` is not a hashable type, so it cannot be an item of a set. Do you want a list of dicts instead?

Comment: @alecxe: yes, I made a correction to the question, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use a list comprehension.  I'm assuming this returns what you want

```
strings = [ 'abc', 'def', 'xyz' ]
result = [ { 'type': type, 'extra_key1':0, 'extra_key2':'no' } for type in strings ]
```

or

```
strings = [ 'abc', 'def', 'xyz' ]
defaults = { 'extra_key1':0, 'extra_key2':'no' }
result = [ { 'type': type }.update( defaults ) for type in strings ]
```